# How can I add a folder to a website that is not in the root folder?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, path, directory

Is it possible in a VS 2010 project to add a reference to a folder, which is located outside the root folder of my project?

For instance, I would like to have a folder, with a lot of pictures and other static stuff, common to several projects, and I don't want to duplicate this folder each time. How can I make a reference to this folder and as result it will be seen as a sub-folder of the root directory of my project?

Comment: Since windows vista it should be possible to use symbolic links.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create the folder under your project folder, but don't add it or any of the picture files to your project.  On the web server, you add that folder as a virtual folder.